# Asp.net MVC5 Application_Start happens every request - sometimes multiple times per request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 project combined with Castle Windsor IoC + Nhibernate,

Right now there's not that much on there, but when i debug the Application_Start function in my Global.asax i can see that it is hit for every request,

Sometimes every a few times for one request...

I read that recompile can happen if files were changed in the IIS folder - but i am using IIS Express - and have no idea where that folder is.

We used to have a .mdf + LocalDb for our testing environment, so i thought that might be the issue somehow, so i connect to SqlExpress now, and i took the .mdf out of the solution,

But still the same issue...

What could cause this behavior? and how can i investigate further to why it is happening ?

*I checked - it seems that even when redirecting to different actions it reloads the MVC - After login Application_Start happens 3 times...

Edit 1:

Started adding everything to a new project to find what's causing the issue, the issue appeared when i added the custom NHibernate UserStore we made to use with the new MVC5 Identity

```
public class NhUserStore : IUserStore<User>, IUserPasswordStore<User>
{
    public ISession _session;

    public NhUserStore(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public Task CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_session.Save(user));
    }
...
}
```

I think it's related to the fact the Session is configured in Windsor as LifeStyle.PerWebRequest and NhUserStore depends on Session but i have no idea why

These are our Windsor installers :

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .BasedOn<Controller>()
                            .LifestyleTransient());

        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<ApiController>()
                .LifestyleScoped());
    }
}
```

I noticed in the template of MVC5 there's :

```
    public AccountController()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }
```

so i use NH's session like this :

```
    public AccountController(ISession session)
        : this(new UserManager<User>(new NhUserStore(session)))
    {
    }

    public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
```

I changed the creation of the UserManager to this right now and it fixed half of it, now the MVC restarts only when using the UserStore, and not every request, still multiple times when using UserStore's functionality

Comment: Can't you reproduce the issue on a blank new mvc5 site?

Comment: Trying, so far configured windsor and still no issue, will configure Nhibernate now

Comment: Happens when i add a custom Nhibernate UserStore, hmm

Comment: Try to isolate the issue and post the minimal culprit.

Comment: Added more code, and the culprit

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of taking out code i managed to find the solution,

We had a WebApi DependencyResolver, while i read there's a different one for Mvc and WebApi and they should be configured in Windsor separately,

I took out the custom DependencyResolver and voila :)

I wish there was a good way to find out what's happening in the background in MVC, the health log just shows that it was restarted...if i had a way to find out the actual exception that caused the restart finding the issue would be easy compared to hours and hours of taking out code and retrying, etc...

Thanks for the help everyone